# How to fix the date[] is not assignable to type [date?, date?] in react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, rsuite

What I'm trying to do is to set a date on date range but there's an error which is

```
Type 'Date[]' is not assignable to type '[Date?, Date?]'.

Types of property 'length' are incompatible.

Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0 | 1 | 2'
```

code:

```
const [ dateRange, setDateRange] = useState([new Date('2017-02-01'), new Date('2017-05-20')]);
<DateRangePicker
                    value={dateRange}
                    onChange={value => {
                        this.setState({ value });
                        console.log(value);
                    }} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is to import the valuetype from rsuite

```
import {ValueType} from "rsuite/lib/DateRangePicker";
```

Then define it in your useState

```
const [ dateRange, setDateRange] = useState<ValueType>([new Date('2017-02-01'), new Date('2017-05-20')])

<DateRangePicker
    value={dateRange}
    onChange={value => {
    setDateRange(value);
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest but not "right" way just to make cast

```js
this.setState({ value: value as [Date?, Date?]});
```

or

```js
onChange={value:[Date, Date] => {
```

Better to create `[Date?, Date?]` variable inside your onChange function using the input value variable

Comment: but I need to use the state cause I'll use it to other function when filtering the date.

Comment: There is no problem with the state itself. You just need to check input data to be sure that it will be saved in the right array size and format.